# Bi-Threaded processing in Matlab

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, matlab, gradient-descent

I have a Large-Scale Gradient Descent optimization problem that I am running using Matlab. The code has got two parts:

1. A Sequential update part that fires every iteration that updates the parameter vector.
2. A validation error computation part that fires every 10 iterations or so using the parameter value at the end of the corresponding iteration in which its fired.

The way that I am running this now is to do (1) and (2) sequentially. But (2) takes a lot of time and its not the core part of my routine - I made it just to check the progress and plot the error of my model. Is it possible in Matlab to run (2) in a parallel manner to (1) ? Please note that (1) cannot be run in parallel since it performs sequential update. So a simple 'parfor' usage is not a solution, unless there is a really smart way of doing that.

Comment: do you know how many iterations in total your process (1) will run ? (or is conditioned to some kind of convergence ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Matlab has any way of multi-threading outside of the (rather restricted) parallel computing toolbox. There is a work over which may help you though:

Open 2 sessions of Matlab, sessions `A` and `B` (or instances, or workspaces, however you call it)

- Matlab session `A`:

  - Calculate the 10 iterations of your sequential process (1)
  - Saves the result in a file (*adequately and uniquely named*)
  - Goes on to calculate the next 10 iterations (back to the top of this loop basically)

In parralel:

- Matlab session `B`:

  - Check periodically for the existence of the file written by process `A` (define a timer that will do that at the time interval which make sense for your process, a few seconds or a few minutes ...)
  - If the file exist => load it then do the validation computation (your process (2)) and display/report the results.

note: *This only works if process (1) doesn't need the result of process (2) to run its iterations, but if it is the case I don't know how you could parallelise anyway.*

If you have multiple cores on your machine that should run smoothly, if you have a single core then the 2 sessions will have to share and you will see a performance impact.

Comment: I think this is a smart way to do it. Thanks! As for your previous comment, It is indeed conditioned on convergence but right now I am setting an iteration limit and looking at how the function behaves for different parameter configurations.